Changes to FxProperties Key do not automatically take effect
I've been trying to change the equalization preset via cmd so I can make a batch script to switch between them easily.
I found out these two are the ones I need to change, but they won't make any effect until I manually switch them inside the Realtek Audio Manager.
https://i.sstatic.net/bZoxaFDU.png
Is there a way to reload the preset without getting into the Audio Manager?
Also tried SoundVolumeView, but I couldn't find a way to change the REG_BINARY value, it makes it a DWORD.

Unfortunately, changing the equalization preset via the command line and having it take effect immediately is tricky because Realtek Audio Manager requires a manual refresh. A potential workaround is to use a script to automate opening the Realtek Audio Manager and triggering the preset change, but this isn't as seamless as doing it purely via command line. Tools like SoundVolumeView don't support modifying REG_BINARY values, so you'd need a custom solution or script to handle this.
